# Web scraping: read all href

Tags: python, regex, urllib

I write a small script to read all hrefs from web page with python.
But it has a problem. It doesn't read `href="pages.php?ef=fa&page=n_fullstory.php&NewsIDn=1648"` for example.

code:

```
import urllib
import re

urls = ["http://something.com"]

regex='href=\"(.+?)\"'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[0])
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
hrefs = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print hrefs
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: General suggestion: don't parse HTML with regexes. While your particular case can be implemented, if you'll need more it can get really messy real fast. Use a proper parsing library instead. Check out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html). Or maybe even [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use BEautifulSoup and requests for static websites. it is a great module for web scraping, use the code and easily you can get the value inside the href tag. hope it helps

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'whatever url you want to parse'

result = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content,'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```